# Error connecting to Infinispan 13.0.1 cluster from a web application deployed in Wildfly 9 server

Tags: java-ee-7, infinispan, wildfly-9

I'm trying to connect from a web application deployed in Wildfly 9 server to an Infinispan cluster, and as many tutorials I try I always get the same error.

Any ideas? Thanks!

ERROR:

```
12:07:31,908 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 4) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: (undefined) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"service-ear.ear\".\"service-ejb.jar\".component.CacheController.START" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"service-ear.ear\".\"service-ejb.jar\".component.CacheController.START: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: org.infinispan.client.hotrod.exceptions.TransportException:: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    Caused by: org.infinispan.client.hotrod.exceptions.TransportException:: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException"}
```

The code is doing this:

ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

```
Properties p = new Properties();
try(Reader r = new FileReader("/srv/ws-xpto/hotrod-client.properties")) {
   p.load(r);
   builder.withProperties(p);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Error loading infinispan hotrod-client.properties file");
}
remoteCacheManager = new RemoteCacheManager(builder.build());
cache = remoteCacheManager.getCache("teste");
```

And the properties file having this:

```
infinispan.client.hotrod.server_list=155.10.6.87:11222;155.10.6.87:11322
infinispan.client.hotrod.auth_username=admin
infinispan.client.hotrod.auth_password=pass
```

Comment: Which version of the client libraries are you using?

Comment: Could you please post the full stacktrace?